# How to load a Spinner with Simple Json Array using json class in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I have a Json Array and i want it to load it in Android Spinner. I tried many things like using Json objects and array list, but it is not giving me correct result. I am using a web service which is returning me in the form of JSON array. I used Json Array class but it returns whole object.
Please see Json array example.

```
<ArrayOfString xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://microsoft.com/webservices/">
<string>1</string>
<string>2</string>
<string>3</string>
<string>4</string>
</ArrayOfString>
```

Answer (score 0):

Although your JSON looks like xml, i will provide code for getting items of JSON array into spinner items.

```
public static final String JSON = "[\"1\", \"2\", \"3\", \"4\", \"444\"]";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ArrayList<String> itemsList = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        JSONArray array = new JSONArray(JSON);

        for (int i=0; i < array.length(); i++) {
            String s = (String) array.get(i);
            itemsList.add(s);
        }

        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =
                new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, itemsList);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

For parsing XML you can use XmlPullParser http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html